# Queryset random order specific to each user with pagination in Django

Tags: django

I want to order queryset randomly which is fixed for each user. When I use `order_by("?")` order change each time but I want different order for each user than don't change next time. For example   for user one order is `<QuerySet [obj1, obj5, obj3, obj4, obj2]>` and for user two is `<QuerySet [obj5, obj2, obj1, obj3, obj4]>` and order for user one don't change but is different from other users. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Django don't have any inbuilt feature to do that kind of shuff. But you can implement that by your own.

To implement that, you need to save a random `seed` value corresponding to a user. I believe you have a user id associated with a user, you can use that as a seed value.

Now you have to use that seed value in Python's built-in `random` to generate a random shuffle.

Example:

```py
import random

numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
print("Original list: ", numbers)
random.seed(4)
random.shuffle(numbers)
print("Shuffled list ", numbers)
# Output [40, 60, 50, 10, 30, 20]

random.seed(4)
random.shuffle(numbers)
print("Reshuffled list ", numbers)
# Output [40, 60, 50, 10, 30, 20]

random.seed(5)
random.shuffle(numbers)
print("Reshuffled list ", numbers)
# Output [60, 40, 10, 20, 30, 50]
```

Convert the same QuerySet into a list and pass it to `random.shuffle(qs_list)` and get the user id and pass it to `random.seed(user_id)`.

Example:

```
import random
random.seed(user_id)
random.shuffle(qs_list)
# qs_list is shuffled according to user's id
```

Comment: Thanks but I wand use it for queryset not for a list. I use queryset with pagination

Comment: There is no way, you can use it with QuerySet. You have to write a custom pagination view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways and it depends on if the main queryset will be changing (adding/removing instances). The easiest way is to store the randomized queryset as variable in `User` model. It can be i.e. `CharField` that is going to store id's divided by commas.

models.py

```
User(...):
    ...
    my_queryset = models.CharField("My QuerySet", max_lenght=512, default="")

    def set_queryset(self, queryset):
        self.my_queryset = ",".join([x.id for x in queryset])
        self.save()

    def get_queryset(self):
        list_of_ids = [int(x) for x in self.my_queryset.split(",")]
        queryset = [queryset.append(MyModel.objects.get(id=i)) for i in list_of_ids]
        return queryset
```

usage:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
randomized_qs = [obj1, obj5, obj3, obj4, obj2]

user.get_queryset()   # gives []
if not user.my_queryset:
    user.set_queryset(randomized_qs)
user.get_queryset()   # gives [obj1, obj5, obj3, obj4, obj2]
```